# R gbm: How does cross validation work in this package?

Tags: r, cross-validation

Can someone provide a work flow about this? For instance, suppose I am doing binary classification,

For each iteration of the algorithm:

1. Randomly sample k*N rows, where k is the bag.fraction, and N is nrow(dataset).
2. Build a classifier using this training sample, suppose we use classification tree here.
3. Predict the terminal node class label.

This how boosting is done without a CV. If I want to do a 3-fold CV, where exactly do I apply it? Between step 1 and 2 or after step 3? Thanks!

Comment: To be more specific, is the cross validation applied to each tree? or is it applied to the entire gbm algorithm? I hope this is clear.

Comment: This *might* be more suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/